# How to delete a set of meshgrid points inside a circle?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to create a meshgrid without some of the points that falls within the circle having specified coordinates and a radius. I am not able to subtract the grid points falling inside the circle. 
Here is my code

```
import math
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 50
x_start, x_end = -2.0, 2.0 
y_start, y_end = -1.0, 1.0


x = numpy.linspace(x_start, x_end, N)
y = numpy.linspace(y_start, y_end, N)

circle_x, circle_y, r= 0.0, 0.0, 0.4

#x.remove((r-circle_x)**2)   #need some help with these two lines
#y.remove((r-circle_y)**2)


X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)


size = 10
fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlabel('x', fontsize = 16)
plt.ylabel('y', fontsize = 16)
plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

meshgrid showing the mesh points## Heading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'd like a scatter plot with just the points outside the circle, use boolean indexing to select only those points from your 2D "meshgridded" array:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 50
x_start, x_end = -2.0, 2.0
y_start, y_end = -1.0, 1.0

x = np.linspace(x_start, x_end, N)
y = np.linspace(y_start, y_end, N)

x0, y0, radius = 0.0, 0.0, 0.4

x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
r = np.sqrt((x - x0)**2 + (y - y0)**2)

outside = r > radius

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', aspect=1.0)

ax.scatter(x[outside], y[outside])

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

On the other hand, if you were using something like `imshow` that requires 2D input, you'd need to either mask the values inside (as @JulienSpronck mentions, though it would be better to set them to `np.nan` or use a masked array than to set them to 0) or set a clip path on the image.

For scatter, however, you don't need 2D input.

---

Boolean indexing on a nD array will return a 1d result.  For example:

```
In [9]: x = np.arange(100).reshape(10, 10)

In [10]: x
Out[10]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
       [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59],
       [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69],
       [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
       [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89],
       [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]])

In [11]: x[x > 75]
Out[11]: 
array([76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92,
       93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99])
```

Because `scatter` is only plotting points, it doesn't care how they're connected, and we can easily use the 1D result of boolean indexing.

On the other hand, if you wanted to plot an image, you'd need a 2D grid.  In that case, you'd want to mask the values instead:

```
In [12]: np.ma.masked_where(x <= 75, x)
Out[12]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --]
 [-- -- -- -- -- -- 76 77 78 79]
 [80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89]
 [90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99]])
```

Notice how this maintains the 2D structure of the input.

On a side note, if this were a floating point array, you could just as easily set the values to `np.nan` instead of masking them. When plotted with `imshow`, the two will behave identically. I used a masked array in this case because `x` was an integer array and can't contain NaN's.

Answer (score 2):

One can not simply remove points from a meshgrid. Instead, you should create another array `Z` as

```
Z = numpy.where((X-circle_x)**2+(Y-circle_y)**2>r**2,1,0)
```

and plot it as

```
plt.scatter(X,Y,Z)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot remove the points within the arrays `x` and `y`. It is a 2D problem and the values that need to be removed from `x` depend on `y` and inversely.

What you can do is operate directly on the mesh you created (`X` and `Y`). For example,

```
import math
import numpy 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


N = 200
x_start, x_end = -2.0, 2.0 
y_start, y_end = -2.0, 2.0


x = numpy.linspace(x_start, x_end, N)
y = numpy.linspace(y_start, y_end, N)

circle_x, circle_y, r= 0.0, 0.0, 0.4

X, Y = numpy.meshgrid(x, y)

## Define points within circle
pts = (X-circle_x)**2+(Y-circle_y)**2 <= r**2

## Create a constant mask over grid
M = numpy.ones(X.shape)
## Assign 0 to mask for all points within circle
M[pts] = 0

size = 10
fig = plt.figure()
plt.imshow(M)
plt.show()
```

This does not remove any points from `X` or `Y`. If instead, you wish to only perform calculations on part of the points, you could do

```
pts = (X-circle_x)**2+(Y-circle_y)**2 > r**2
X = X[pts]
Y = Y[pts]

plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Julien  your first post with the grid plot example is very close to what I am looking for. The issue is that it actually creates the gridpoints and then hides the points lying within the circle (this is what I understand). I however wish to perform further calculations on all the gridpoints that    are present, so I need to have only those gridpoints that are not outside the circle, merely hiding it will not serve my purpose                       but thanks a lot for the detailed explaination

Comment: The points are not hidden nor removed, `X` and `Y` are still complete and all calculations can still be performed on all grid points, and then apply the mask `M` to your results. However, if you want to perform calculations only on the points outside the circle, you can simply define the points you want and re-assign `X` and `Y` to only have the ones you need. See edit of my answer for an example.