# Deleting points on grid outside of boundary condition - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a grid of points (e.g. (1,1), (1,2), (1,3)...(100,99), (100,100)) that is contained in a a pandas dataframe, and also exported as a .csv file.

I then have a boundary condition, for example a circle in the centre of this grid with a diameter of 25. I want to be able to delete all the points outside of the circle, and just keep the internal ones in a new dataframe.

I can get the boundaries of the circle, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, but when I delete the points with respect to this, I get a square (due to the min/max values being integers that just find the furthest points from the centre).

Is it possible to save all the points internal to the circle? Preferably with a universal method that could be applied to elipses, etc.

EDIT: I've found this, which is similar: [How to delete a set of meshgrid points inside a circle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330307/how-to-delete-a-set-of-meshgrid-points-inside-a-circle)

But relies on the dimensions of the circle being entered in the code, so is not universal. As I have the boundary points of the shape, I would have to calculate it, and assume it is circular (which it may not always be). Is there a way to adapt this so I could create a "filled" area using the boundary points, and then perform the boolean operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is...

> Is it possible to save all the points internal to the circle?

Yes, it is possible, and there is a formula for this. The function below `distance_from` is basic euclidean distance for 2D plans.

```
def encloses(center_of_circle, vector2D, radius_of_circle):
    return distance_from(center_of_circle, vector2D) <= radius_of_circle
```

This function `encloses()` will return True if the vector2D is in the circle. False if not. Filter your pandas DataFrame with it.

I suspect, as you got a square instead of a circle, that you were computing the formula `encloses()` for a square, and not a circle...

Comment: Perform the operation for the 2 circles, and combine the DataFrame of points without duplicates ? You will then have a DataFrame of points in your circles.

Comment: @Mikeh12 When you will be done, and if the answer has helped you : I invite you to close it by accepting the answer.