# How to restrict the vector field to a circle of certain radius?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I'm plotting the vector magnetic potential of a finite wire. The resultant vector field should be circular and pointing upwards (z-direction). The field I get is pointing upwards, but it's not circular. It looks like a square. Can someone please point out the mistake I'm making.

[image: that's the result I'm getting]

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

l = 10
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 1, 20),
                      np.linspace(-1, 1, 20),
                      np.linspace(-1, 1, 3))



u = 0
v = 0
w = np.log(2*l/((x**2 + y**2)**0.5))

ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=0.1, color = 'black')

plt.show()
```

Comment: The code does what it should do. How do you want this to look?

Comment: Instead of these squares, I want it to look like the vectors are emanating from disks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a mask, as was pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330307/how-to-delete-a-set-of-meshgrid-points-inside-a-circle).

for your specific example, you can create this mask by calculating which points in your xy plane lie inside the circle:

```
x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 1, 20),
                      np.linspace(-1, 1, 20),
                      np.linspace(-1, 1, 3))

radius = 1
mask = x**2 + y**2 <= radius
```

Now apply the mask

```
x, y, z = x[mask], y[mask], z[mask]


u = 0
v = 0
w = np.log(2*l/((x**2 + y**2)**0.5))

ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=0.1, color = 'black')

plt.show()
```

[image]